Args without explicit invoking Python
A basic Python question, but I'm confused. Go easy on me:
I have a simple script:
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys # args
print (sys.argv)

When run using python python myscript.py 1 2 3 I get:
['myscript.py', '1', '2', '3']
However, when run by omitting "python" using just myscript.py 1 2 3 I get:
[C:\\Path\\To\\myscript.py']
Is there a way to differentiate between arguments being set and bypassing python??

In the scond case the script is started by the shell (Bash), and the arguments 1 2 3 are captured by the shell and not passed on to the Python driver.

@OldBoy, I'm not sure it's going to be bash here so much as something weird with windows. Testing the same thing on linux with bash/zsh, I get the same results for both.

Does this answer your question? Python Script does not take sys.argv in Windows

@Holloway Oops, yes I missed that, and your link contains the correct answer.

@Holloway I've changed the reg value to "C:\path_to_python\python3.exe" "%1" %* and it now both methods produce the same results
